# Different migration behavior when running with `--database`

Tags: django, django-migrations

We have a specific migration that fails when run with `--database` rather than running on the `default` connection.

The migration attempts to insert a row omitting one of the fields. The model that has non-null fields and a default defined in the model. When run against the default database, this migration succeeds, but when run with `--database` it fails as it tries to insert `null`.

This is not specific to the database being targeted. If I take the definition of this second database and plug it into `default` and run the migration, it succeeds. It only fails when it runs with a non-default database connection.

This is happening on 2.2.28, but I tried upgrading up to 3.2.20 and the same behavior persists (not able to try with 4.x due to postgres version conflicts).